# Trouble disconnecting and reconnecting socket (C++, winsock2)

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, tcp, winsock2

I want the client program (TCP) to be ready to connect to the server program whenever the server starts to accept() incoming connections (the client program should always stay running, and the server program can start or end whenever it wants). The client code looks like this:

```
while (1) {

    //Wait for the server to accept the connection:
    while (connect(socket,(sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr))!=0) {cout<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;}

    //Send whatever data...

}
```

On the first execution of the while (1) loop, everything runs as expected; when the client is connected to the server, it sends all the data, and the the server program is ended. Then I want the client to wait again at the while (connect(...,...,...)!=0) loop until the server starts again and accept()s a connection, but it does not connect to the server and WSAGetLastError() returns 10056, indicating that the socket is already connected (why?). I heard that you cannot reconnect the client after calling closesocket() on the socket, so I tried to disconnect the client before reconnecting by adding shutdown(socket,SD_SEND) to the while (1) loop but that doesn't work either.

Is there anything I can do besides repetitively waiting for the client program to end and starting it again? Is there some way to disconnect the client from the server program such that the client can reconnect later?

Comment: What???  Close the socket!  'I heard that you cannot reconnect the client after calling closesocket() on the socket' - where did you hear that?

Comment: When the server program ends, does it close its end of the connection?   It should do.

Comment: @MartinJames it doesn't close the connection ._. It keeps returning 10056 no matter how long I wait...

Comment: Never mind me - I'm tired and starting to spout nonsense.  In my apps, I create another socket at the top of the 'connect/read/close' loop.  I was wrong.   Obviously, this reloads the same socket var with a new socket.

Answer (score 2):

There's something seriously wrong with your application logic. You don't *need* to reconnect a connected socket; you *can't* reconnect a connected socket; and you can't reconnect a socket that has been closed, unless you're exploring one of the remote corners of the Windows API.

Comment: Why can you not connect up again after closing?  I'm sure I've done that before!

Comment: @EJP If I close the server program and start it again, how do I define  the socket I will use on the server if I'm not supposed to call connect() again?

Comment: Is there any way at all I can kill the connection and start it again?

Comment: @AwaisChishti False alarm - I looked at my code and it simply creates a socket at the top of the 'connect/read' loop.  So, a different client socket is used for each connect().  Brain fade:(

Comment: @AwaisChishti do what I do and failed to explain correctly. Allocate the client socket at the top of the loop so that a new one is used each time.  Close it when the connection closes or some error/exception happens and loop back round to reconnect.

Comment: +1 for EJP for correct interpretation of what it needed, (unlike mine:).

Comment: @MartinJames adding socket=socket(...,...,...); at the end of the while(1) loop worked for me. Thanks for helping.

Comment: If you use `ConnectEx()` and `DisconnectEx()`, you can reuse the same `SOCKET` handle over and over without having to close it and create a new one each time.